# Excel (Mantain data to same reference when adding new row) -extracting data based on conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sample data]

This is a sample data. My aim is to automatically filter rows with outcome "escalation" 
The formula I am using is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("escalation",$B$2:$B$11)),ROW($B$2:$B$11),""),ROW()-1)),"")
```

This works well for the purpose of automatically filtering rows with the outcome "escalation"

[image]

I have added an extra field on my new table named 'comments' in which I manually add comments. The issue now is that, when I change outcome from no to escalation on my main table, the data gets added to my filtered table but the comments do not change accordingly.

Example :

Changing EnquiryRef 43543 from no to escalation gives the following result on my filtered table.

[image]

The comment for enquiryref 4324888 ends up with enquiryref 43543.

Is there anyway that I can solve this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Short Answer: No, not with formula, your comments would need to be on the data side not the outcome side.  This is not a relational data base and Excel does not link cells to other cells.

Comment: the long Answer is, if the comments can be formulated, where we can tie the text shown to the data then yes it is possible, but I do not see in your example data if the data itself can be used to trigger specific output or not.

Comment: The answer I think is using autofilters. Not formulas. You can filter rows based on column conditions and it's easier.